# Mult_phrase_match from multiple field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two document in elastic search on feedText key

1. We are testing bad word infiltration
2. 2nd document for bad word testing using elastic search.

Now I want exact phrase matching with highlighting feature

1. for bad word testing
2. testing bad word

I want a response like:
We are *testing bad word* infiltration
2nd document *for bad word testing* using elastic search.

I am trying to use bool query with should.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "feedText": {
                        "query": "for bad word testing ",
                          "type" : "phrase"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "feedText": {
                        "query": " testing bad word ",
                        "type" : "phrase"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},

"highlight": {
    "fields": {
        "feedText": {},
        "feedMessage" :{}

    }
}
```

Comment: Problem statement is not clear from your question. What does this mean `I want a response like: We are testing bad word infiltration 2nd document for bad word testing using elastic search.`

Comment: I want a response like :We are </em>testing bad word</em> infiltration
2nd document </em>for bad word testing</em> using elastic search.